# Get the SKU in a Product list sales report

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, sku

Using WooCommerce, I have this code that output a product list report:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'total_sales',
            'value' => 0,
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    )
);
$output = array_reduce( get_posts( $args ), function( $result, $post ) {
    return $result .= '<tr><td>' . $post->post_title . '</td><td>' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'total_sales', true ) . '</td></tr>';
} );
echo '<table><thead><tr><th>' . __( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ) . '</th><th>' . __( 'Units Sold', 'woocommerce' ) . '</th></tr></thead>' . $output . '</table>';
```

With that code I would like to list the sales on a Wordpress page.

My question: How to add the SKU to the table?

Thanks

Comment: I have updated my code lightly… there was a syntax error… Let me know if it works for you thanks…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **— Light Update —**

You can add the sku changing a little bit your code  this way:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'total_sales',
            'value' => 0,
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    )
);

$output = array_reduce( get_posts( $args ), function( $result, $post ) {
    return $result .= '
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>' . $post->post_title . '</td>
            <td>' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, "total_sales", true ) .'</td>
            <td>' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, "_sku", true ) .'</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>';
} );

echo '<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>' . __( "Product", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
            <th>' . __( "Units Sold", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
            <th>' . __( "Sku", "woocommerce" ) . '</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>' . $output . '
</table>';
```

I am using here **`get_post_meta( $post->ID, "_sku", true )`** to get the SKU value from wp_postmeta database table…

---

Or alternatively you can use with a product object the method [**`get_sku()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_sku)…

Comment: Thats all? Thank you! I have used the wrong meta key.